Finding an estimator with the least mean squared error
Let $ X_1,...,X_n $ denote a random sample from a $ N(\mu,\sigma^2) $ distribution,
where the mean and the variance are both unknown.
Consider estimators of the form $$ T_c = c\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)$$
where c is a constant.
Find the estimator of $ \sigma^2 $ having the least mean squared error in the class $ T_c $
I know that the MSE is the variance plus the bias squared but can't work out how to do this question as this sort of maths is very new to me.
